# Calculated Member as an existing measure filtered by both a tuple and a set

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube, ssas-2012

I'm looking to create a calculated member with SQL Server Data Tools Analysis Services on an OLAP cube that *combines* the following filtering approaches:

**Tuple**

```
(
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].&[1],
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 1].&[Y],
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 2].&[N],
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 3].&[N],
    [Measures].[Count]
)
```

**Set as a single member**

```
SUM(    
    EXCEPT(
        [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].[Year],
        {
            [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].&[1]
        }
    ),
    [Measures].[Count]
)
```

The `[Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year]` has members of values 1, 2, 3, 4 and I essentially want the calculated member to provide `[Measures].[Count]` filtered on:

- Include all `[Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year]` members EXCEPT `[Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].&[1]`
- `[Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 1].&[Y]`
- `[Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 2].&[N]`
- `[Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 3].&[N]`

I recognize the `SUM` function may be the wrong approach in attempting to combine these filters.

I found the accepted answer to the article [MDX Calculated member filter by dimension attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582473/mdx-calculated-member-filter-by-dimension-attribute) exceptionally helpful up to this point.

Perhaps fundamentally there is something wrong in this way of thinking. Open to suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there buddy.

Just extending on the concept of `set` and `tuple`, and adding on the concept of `crossjoin` or `*`, here is what should work:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.YourCalculatedMember AS

SUM(
    EXCEPT(
            [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].[Year],
            {
                [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].&[1]
            }
          ) *
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 1].&[Y] *
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 2].&[N] *
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 3].&[N]
    ,
    [Measures].[Count]
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could even just drop the measure and create the member on one of the Attribute hierarchies. Then you can use different measures against it:

```
WITH MEMBER [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 1].[YourCalculatedMember] AS
SUM(
    EXCEPT(
            [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].[Year],
            {
                [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Year].&[1]
            }
          ) *
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 1].&[Y] *
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 2].&[N] *
    [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 3].&[N]
  )
SELECT
   {
     [Measures].[Count],
     [Measures].[Revenue]
   } on 0,
   {  
     [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 1].[YourCalculatedMember], 
     [Enrolment Planning Actuals].[Attribute 1].&[Y]
   } on 1
FROM [YourCube];
```

Comment: Thanks for your input as well, this is a new perspective for me that I may incorporate in other instances.